# First Vertex insert

Tags: mesh

In Edit mode I can insert Vertices with Ctrl-Click. The new Vertex will be linked to the previously selected one by an Edge. Great.

But how do I insert the FIRST one ? I cannot enter Edit mode with an empty scene, and Ctrl-Click doesn't work in Object mode. What's the trick to have my first Vertex on scene in Edit mode ?

Comment: There is a way to add a single vertex as any other objects: http://blenderartists.org/forum/attachment.php?attachmentid=316285&d=1403282030 Here's a tutorial showing how to do it: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8LRfiBN8H5U It isn't a simple one though :).

Answer (score 9):

You could add any object (mesh) <kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>A</kbd>,

- Change to *Edit Mode*
- Select all vertices <kbd>A</kbd>
- Use <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>M</kbd> (merge).

Answer (score 4):

Typically to do this you would start by adding a plane and deleting all but one of the vertices.

Answer (score 4):

There's an add-on which ships with Blender called *Extra Objects*. If you enable it you will get extra options in the *Add Mesh* menu. One of the new options is *Single vert*. It's made for exactly this purpose; quickly start making meshes.

[image]

You *can* set a shortcut for that operation, by right-clicking *Add Single Vert* menu item and choosing *Add Shortcut*

Comment: I don't know why, but I installed the Extra Objects addon and I don't have the options you have: http://gfycat.com/AnchoredGloriousFlies

Comment: I just installed the latest Blender from `builder.blender.org` and that menu appears the same as in my screenshot. It's entirely possible that another addon you have enabled has manipulated the add_mesh menu but not considered that other addons might be present, and not accounted for them.

Comment: I'm using Blender 2.75a and I couldn't enable the Mesh/Extra Objects add-on. Moreover Documentation refers to a few extra objects only, not to Add Single Vert … Maybe this is no longer available ?

Comment: @Stephane it's more likely that the docs aren't updated as frequently as the code in the add-on. I get blender from [builder.blender.org](https://builder.blender.org/download/) , which has two scripts folders `addons` and `addons_contrib`. Add-Mesh Extra Objects is located in `addons`. The content of `addons` should be the same as official 2.75a releases, if they are different it is because the builder.blender.org builds contain updated addons..

Comment: see : http://i.stack.imgur.com/GBjfk.png

Answer (score 3):

Being in *Edit Mode* go to *Mesh* and check the ***Auto Merge Editing*** box. This function automatically merges vertices.
[image]

Now add a plane (or every other object you like), go to the *Tool Shelf* (<kbd>T</kbd>) options and change the ***Radius*** to ***0***.
[image]

Please note, that if you add the same object again (a plane in this case) it will have the same settings as previously added one, so you'll have to adjust them in a *Tool Shelf* panel.

Comment: Yes, but, how do I enter Edit mode with an empty scene ?

Comment: You have to add any object first, then go to the Edit Mode and enable Auto Merge Editing and then delete the object. It's quite strange but you can't enable this function with an empty scene. I should have written about it in my answer.

Answer (score 3):

Youd don't even have to leave or merge any verices, you can just create a plane and then delete it completely in edit mode by pressing <kbd>Delete</kbd> key or <kbd>X</kbd> key, and now you can create vertices including the first vertice by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> LMB.

Answer (score 1):

In Object mode you can add a single Vertex object.

Then you can enter edit mode and keep adding vertices with <kbd>⎈ Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>[image: LMB] LMB</kbd>

[image]